# How can I push to the previous repository

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I need help with a problem related to git and GitHub:

I have a react app and I pushed it to [my repository](https://github.com/Hamza-Noah/My-First-React-App) on Github.

After that, I needed to push it as a live version. As this did not work as expected, I deleted the repository. Then, I edited the project on my local machine and want to push it to the deleted repository again.

Here I am stuck, I want to push the edited files to the old repository. I searched and asked about how can I do it but did not find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I have edited your text a bit to understand it but I still have questions. Your repo is still there! Did you delete the repository online or on your computer? Do you mean branches? What happens when you do `git status` in your local directory? What is returned for `git remote -v`?

Comment: Ah ok, now the online repository is empty... If you still have your .git directory locally, you can copy this to the location of your local files. If git status and git remote return something, you can maybe just push again as usual.

Comment: Or, you can run `git clone https://github.com/Hamza-Noah/My-First-React-App.git` to create a new local empty repository, and copy your code over to the new folder created by the command.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change the git remote URL repo and push code into that repo

first `git remote set-url` for remote

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/NEW_REPO_NAME
```

now check it the remote url change or not then push the code into that repo

```
git remote -v origin
```